# Git Merge Recursive Ours - Command Syntax Example

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

What is the right format for a git merge with a strategy of recursive ours?  (not to be confused with the git merge ours strategy)

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

I tried a bunch of ways and it doesn't seem to work.

```
git merge foo -s recursive-ours  // doesn't work
git merge foo -s recursive ours // doesn't work
git merge foo -s recursive -ours // doesn't work
...
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`git merge -s recursive -X ours foo`

Comment: Sorry I no longer have this GIT problem so I cannot verify the solution, but I'm gonna accept the answer since it's the only one and Gabe took the time to reply. :)

Comment: Thanks for this too; @QuangVan - re: verification, I just checked `git help merge` states there is a switch `-X <strategy-option>`; my problem was, I didn't know what to look for in the help page, and this answer helped. Cheers!